# How to pass an argument to value in forms.BooleanField

Tags: django, forms

I try to pass an argument to value in a form field but in the template it displays this argument as a string of characters and not as a variable.

```
checkbox =forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkbox', 'value':'{{ ue.code_ue }}'}))
```

```
def liste_ue(request, filiere):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        supp_ue_bloc_form = SuppUEBlocForms(request.POST);

        if supp_ue_bloc_form.is_valid():
            liste = supp_ue_bloc_form.cleaned_data['action'];
            check = request.POST.getlist('checkbox');
            return HttpResponse(check);

        else:
            return HttpResponse(supp_ue_bloc.is_valid());

    else:
        ues = UE.objects.filter(filiere__nom_filiere=filiere);
        supp_ue_bloc_form = SuppUEBlocForms(initial={'checkbox':ues[0].code_ue})
        return render(request, 'felyn/admin/liste_ue.html', {'supp_ue_bloc_form': supp_ue_bloc_form,\
            'ues': ues, 'filiere': request.session.get('filiere')});



<table class="table table-striped">
        <caption class="">Liste des UEs de la filière {{ filiere }}</caption>
        <thead>  
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall"/></th>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Intitulé</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Niveau</th>
                <th>Filière</th>
                <th>Semestre</th>
                <th>      </th>
                <th>      </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>  
            {% for ue in ues %} <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value={{ ue.code_ue }} />-->
            <tr>
                <th> {{ supp_ue_bloc_form.checkbox.errors }} {{ supp_ue_bloc_form.checkbox }}</th>
                <td>{{ ue.code_ue }}</td>
                <td>{{ ue.intitule_ue }}</td>
                <td>{{ ue.type_ue }}</td>
                <td>{{ ue.niveau }}</td>
                <td>{{ ue.filiere }}</td>
                <td>{{ ue.semestre }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'supprimer_ue' code=ue.code_ue %}">Supprimer</a></td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'modifier_ue' code=ue.code_ue %}">Modifier</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

as you can see, the value of value differs on each line and I need its values ​​to perform ttraitemess

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why?

Comment: I want value equal to the value of ue.code_ue

Comment: But, what? A boolean is true or false. And what is `ue` here? You don't define it anywhere. Again, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: in my template it would be like this : <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value={{ ue.code_ue }} / > where in the browser, we would have some thing like this :   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="INF430" / >

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyForm (forms.Form):
    checkbox =forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class':'checkbox'}))
```

In your view

```
form = MyForm(initial={'checkbox':ue.code_ue})
context = {
    'form':form
}
```

assuming us.code_ue is True/False (ie boolean).

If you're trying to give it a label then
`form.fields['checkbox'].label = ue.code_ue` should come after you've initiated the form.
    render(request, 'MyHTML.html', context)

Comment: it's a bit like that. but value has the same value everywhere and that's not what I want. here is the code of my view and my template